# Scanning for words in a string with no spaces

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to extract words from a string in Ruby. For example, if I have this:

"12jdfndjseven456sfjithree"

I want to get an array with ["seven", "three"]. The only words that I'm looking for are numbers one...nine so not just any word. Is there a way to scan for these specific words and then map them if they appear?

I also want them to be in the order they appear in the string, so don't just want to do if/include as I think this will put them in the order it scans them for (unless I'm wrong?)

I think maybe you can do a regex scan, but I'm terrible at regex so not sure where to start as it's words not numbers.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify the only words I'm looking for are specifically: "one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine" so I can completely ignore any other words.

Comment: Please add a 'regex' tag and consider removing all but the 'ruby' tag. `'string'`, for example, is not likely to be a search term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have array of target words, you can join array of words with [pipe](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Alternation) `|`

> The vertical bar metacharacter (`|`) may be used within parentheses to express alternation: two or more subexpressions any of which may match the target string

And after that [scan](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/String.html#method-i-scan) using this Regexp

```rb
string = "12jdfndjseven456sfjithree"

words = %w[one two three four five six seven eight nine]

pattern = Regexp.union(words) # or %r{#{words.join('|')}} or /#{words.join('|')}/
# => /one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine/

string.scan(pattern)
# => ["seven", "three"]
```

Comment: `Regexp` provides the [`::union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union) method for this exact purpose e.g. `Regexp.union(words)`.

Comment: Just a follow up question - how would I add a positive lookahead to the pattern so it recognises words even if they are overlapping? eg. twone (two/one)

Comment: It will work even if words are overlap by each other. `"twoone".scan(/one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine/) #=> ["two", "one"]`

Comment: @linneabell You can make a code that recognises words even if they are overlapping by using the `.select` finder on the `words` array with `.include?`. The performance can be a bit lower, but we will no longer use regexes, which increases the code readability → `numbers.select { |number| 'twone'.include?(number) }`

Comment: @linneabell Sorry, the performance will not be lower, it actually **outperforms** the solution with regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using regexes on the answer by directly asking if the input string includes any of your selected numbers.

```rb
input = "12jdfndjseven456sfjithree"

numbers = %w[one two three four five six seven eight nine]

output = numbers.select { |number| input.include?(number) }

# Result: ["three", "seven"]
```

This solution also works for the question you asked on your previous comments

> @linneabell: Just a follow up question - how would I add a positive lookahead to the pattern so it recognises words even if they are overlapping? eg. twone (two/one)

```rb
input = "twone"

numbers = %w[one two three four five six seven eight nine]

output = numbers.select { |number| input.include?(number) }

# Result: ["one", "two"]
```

Through some benchmarking, I found that this solution seems to perform better than the one using regex. It also appears more readable because it uses a more natural language approach to identify numbers in the input string. Moreover, it can detect numbers even when they're overlapping, like in examples such as `"twone"`,`"sevenine"` and `"threeight"`.

Finally, if preserving the order of the matched numbers is crucial to you, one way could be sorting the output based on their positions within the input string.

```rb
output.sort_by { |number| input.index(number) }
```

Even with this extra line of code included, the benchmarking tests suggest that it should still outperform regexes in terms of speed.

Comment: What's about `oneone`?

Comment: Finding repeated numbers within the string was not something requested on the question.